# How the authors conclude ${Y_{S}} =\phi_{N}\left({X_{S}}\right)$ in the proof of Optional Sampling Theorem?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, martingales, stopping-times

I'm reading about martingale and stopping time from my lecture note. The authors first start with a proposition and a corollary:

> [image]
>   [image]

and then my proposition of interest:

> [image]

The authors said that $\mathbb{E}\left[\phi_{N}\left(X_{0}\right)\right] \le \mathbb{E}\left[\phi_{N}\left({X_{S}}\right)\right]$ is obtained by applying **Corollary 66** to the stopping times $0$ and $S$.

**My understanding:** Let $Y_n = \phi_N (X_n)$. Then by **Proposition 33(ii)**, we get $(Y_n)$ is a bounded sub-martingale. By **Corollary 66**, we get $(Y_0, Y_S)$ is a sub-martingale w.r.t $(\mathcal F_0, \mathcal F_S)$. Hence $\mathbb E [Y_0] \le \mathbb E [Y_S]$ or equivalently $\mathbb{E}\left[\phi_{N}\left(X_{0}\right)\right] \le \mathbb E [{Y_{S}}]$.

> **My question:** How can the authors conclude that ${Y_{S}} =\phi_{N}\left({X_{S}}\right)$?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't get your question. By definition, $Y_n = \phi_N(X_n)$. Thus, $$Y_S = \sum_{n} Y_n 1_{\{S=n\}} = \sum_n \phi_N(X_n) 1_{\{S=n\}} = \phi(X_S),$$ no?

Comment: Hi @saz, I've just broken down the steps to verify if I correctly understand your idea. Did you mean $$\begin{aligned} Y_S &= Y_S\sum_{n}  \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}}\\ &= \sum_{n} Y_S \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}}\\  &= \sum_{n} Y_n \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\&= \sum_n \phi_N(X_n) \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\ &= \sum_n \phi_N(X_S) \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\&=\phi_N(X_S) \sum_n  \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\ &= \phi_N (X_S) \end{aligned}$$?

Comment: Well, yes. Equivalently, you can read it as a pointwise identity: For fixed $\omega$ set $n=S(\omega)$, then $Y_S(\omega) = Y_n(\omega)=X_N(X_n) = X_N (X_S)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my confusion @saz :)))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${Y_{S}} =\phi_{N}\left({X_{S}}\right)$ is actually correct with the following reasoning $$\begin{aligned} Y_S &= Y_S\sum_{n}  \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}}\\ &= \sum_{n} Y_S \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}}\\  &= \sum_{n} Y_n \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\&= \sum_n \phi_N(X_n) \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\ &= \sum_n \phi_N(X_S) \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\&=\phi_N(X_S) \sum_n  \mathbf 1_{\{S=n\}} \\ &= \phi_N (X_S) \end{aligned}$$